# sine/cos for triangle that can be mapped to the left side of the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

Following is the unit circle (I am sorry if my drawing is not 100% accurate).

[image]

We know that:
$OP = 1$
$PQ = \sin \theta \cdot OP = \sin \theta$
$OQ = \cos \theta \cdot OP = \cos \theta$
$OAQ = 90 \space degrees$
$QAP = 90 \space degrees$

$\theta$ is the $AOQ$ angle of course.

In regards to the length $OA$ is the following reasoning correct?
$OA = \cos \theta \cdot  OQ=\cos \theta \cdot \cos \theta = (\cos \theta)^2$

I suspect that it is wrong because I should consider $OP$ as the level and hence with this approach is is the same as $-\cos \theta$ or something like that.
Can someone help me understand if we can do the approach I mentioned and if not the error in the thinking?

Please note:
I am not asking about how to calculate $OA$ because I have already found the solution in a resource which follows a different approach.
I am trying to understand the concept better and the issue with using the approach I mentioned

**Update:**
My concern was that since if we transpose the $OPQ$ to the left side for example, the signs change and if I work with $OAQ$ for which the angle $\theta$ is with a different horizontal level/line how $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are defined has to change too.
So is there any change in how we define them if we work considering $OP$ as the "level" instead of $OQ$?
This is the part I am confused. Basically if I rotate the circle then $PQ$ becomes the horizontal line that $AQ$ forms a right angle and since it is in the left of $O$ it would be $-\cos \theta$.
I think the diagram will be as follows:

[image]

So since it is in the left side it would be $-\cos \theta$?

Can someone help me understand this better?

**Update 2:**
To put the question differently in the following diagram:
[image]

does the fact that the triangle ABC can be mapped to the left side of the unit circle affect the definition of its $\cos \theta$?
I.e.
Would it be $\cos \theta = -\frac{b}{a}$ because it can be mapped to the place of the unit circle between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $3\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Alternatively you could use $OA\times OP=OQ^2$.

Comment: @Etemon: I have seen a solution reversing/flipping the triangles $OAQ$ and $QAP$ so that they have the same "level" (i.e. the right angle is with the $OQ$) and hence thought my approach has some logical flaw

Comment: No sometimes reading answers in books might be confusing. You've correctly used $\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$

Comment: @Etemon: So the horizontal line in the original triangle $OPQ$ which is the level does not have any influence on changing triangles?

Comment: No it doesn't in fact if you consider a right triangle with an acute angle $\theta$,  you rotate it without $\theta$ (hence $\cos\theta$) getting change. Furthermore note that $\cos\theta>0$ for $0< \theta<\frac{\pi}2$ and $\cos\theta<0$ for $\frac{\pi}2<\theta<\pi$.

Comment: @Etemon: I updated my post. Why is it not $-\cos \theta$?

Answer (score 0):

$OA = OQ\cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=\cos^2\theta$ hence you are right!

Comment: No, seems I was right by coincidence. Could you explain that $sin$ and how you derived it?

Comment: Check my update if possible please